# How to get the value of radio buttons?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to retrieve the values ​​of my radio buttons, however it only retrieves them when I create inputs, knowing that I don't use a form to save my data is there a solution to save them without that ? Or do I have to use a form for that?
I have a django backend and an angular frontend

**html**

```
<label for="name">Nom de la flotte à créer</label>
<input class="Nflotte" [(ngModel)]="SelectedFlotte" type="text"   #flotteName placeholder="Nom de la flotte" required>

<form  novalidate>

<table class="blueTable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th style="width: 700px;">num_facade</th>
    <th style="width: 700px;">num_immatriculation_ef</th>
    
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody style="margin: 15px;">
        <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="masterSelected" name="list_name" value="m1"
        (change)="checkUncheckAll()"  /> <strong>Sélectionner tout les engins</strong>

        <tr class="list-group" style="list-style-type: none;" *ngFor="let engin of engins | appFilter: searchText">
            <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="engin.isSelected" #fEngins name="list_engins[]" value="{{engin.identifiant}}"
        (change)="isAllSelected()" />
            <th>{{engin.num_facade}}</th>
            <th>{{engin.num_immatriculation_ef}}</th>
        </tr>


    </tbody>
    </table>    

</form>


<div class="list-cf">
    <div class="vertical">
        <label htmlFor="Sélectionner un calculateur" class="wcs-container">

            <span class="text">Sélectionner un calculateur</span></label>
        <ul class="check-cf">
            <li *ngIf="SelectedSerie?.code_serie_materiel === Z50000" show>
                <input [(ngModel)]="ccucbmv1Selected"  #fcalc class="wcs-checkbox" value="CCUCBM V1" type="radio" name="checkbox-calc" id="checkbox-id">
                <span class="wcs-checkmark" >CCUCBM V1</span>
            </li>
            <li *ngIf="SelectedSerie?.code_serie_materiel === Z50000" show>
                <input [(ngModel)]="ccucbmv8Selected" #fcalc class="wcs-checkbox" type="radio" name="checkbox-calc" id="checkbox-id" value="CCUCBM V8">
                <span class="wcs-checkmark">CCUCBM V8</span>
            </li>
            <li *ngIf="SelectedSerie?.code_serie_materiel === Z50000" show>
                <input [(ngModel)]="ccucv3Selected" #fcalc class="wcs-checkbox" type="radio" name="checkbox-calc" id="checkbox-id" value="CCUC V3">
                <span class="wcs-checkmark">CCUC V3</span>
            </li >
            <li *ngIf="SelectedSerie?.code_serie_materiel === Z58000" show>
                <input class="wcs-checkbox" type="radio" name="checkbox-calc" id="checkbox-id" value="Netbox SIE en Z3-1">
                <span class="wcs-checkmark">Netbox SIE en Z3-1</span>
            </li>
            <li *ngIf="SelectedSerie?.code_serie_materiel === Z58000" show>
                <input class="wcs-checkbox" type="radio" name="checkbox-calc" id="checkbox-id" value="Netbox AMM en Z3-1">
                <span class="wcs-checkmark">Netbox AMM en Z3-1</span>
            </li>
            <li *ngIf="SelectedSerie?.code_serie_materiel === Z57000" show>
                <input [(ngModel)]="surferSelected" class="wcs-checkbox" type="radio" name="checkbox-calc" id="checkbox-id" value="SURFER en V15">
                <span class="wcs-checkmark">SURFER en V15</span>
            </li>
            <li *ngIf="SelectedSerie?.code_serie_materiel === 'Z55500'">
                <input [(ngModel)]="SboxV13Selected" class="wcs-checkbox" type="radio" name="checkbox-calc" id="checkbox-id" value="S*BOX en V13">
                <span class="wcs-checkmark">S*BOX en V15</span>
            </li>
            <li *ngIf="SelectedSerie?.code_serie_materiel === 'B82500' " show>
                <input [(ngModel)]="NvrSelected" class="wcs-checkbox" type="radio" name="checkbox-calc" id="checkbox-id" value="NVR">
                <span class="wcs-checkmark">NVR</span>
            </li>
            <li *ngIf="SelectedSerie?.code_serie_materiel === 'Z27500' " show>
                <input [(ngModel)]="NvrSelected" class="wcs-checkbox" type="radio" name="checkbox-calc" id="checkbox-id" value="NVR">
                <span class="wcs-checkmark">NVR</span>
            </li>
            <li *ngIf="SelectedSerie?.code_serie_materiel === 'X76500' " show>
                <input [(ngModel)]="NvrSelected" class="wcs-checkbox" type="radio" name="checkbox-calc" id="checkbox-id" value="NVR">
                <span class="wcs-checkmark">NVR</span>
            </li>
            <li *ngIf="SelectedSerie?.code_serie_materiel === 'B81500' " show>
                <input [(ngModel)]="NvrSelected" class="wcs-checkbox" type="radio" name="checkbox-calc" id="checkbox-id" value="NVR">
                <span class="wcs-checkmark">NVR</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
        
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <div class="vertical">
    
        <label htmlFor="Sélectionner un type de fichier" class="wcs-container">

            <span class="text">Sélectionner un type de fichier</span></label>
        <ul class="check-cf" style="column-count: 2;">
        <ng-template *ngIf="ccucbmv1Selected checked " >
            <li >
                
                <input class="wcs-checkbox" type="radio" name="checkbox-id" id="checkbox-id">
                <span class="wcs-checkmark">Variables.xml</span>
                
            </li>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template></ng-template>
            <li *ngIf="ccucbmv8Selected checked "  >
                <input class="wcs-checkbox" type="radio" name="checkbox-id" id="checkbox-id" #ftype value="Variables.xml">
                <span class="wcs-checkmark">Variables.xml</span>
            </li>
            <li *ngIf="surferSelected checked " show >
                <input class="wcs-checkbox" type="radio" name="checkbox-id" id="checkbox-id">
                <span class="wcs-checkmark">Variables.xml</span>
            </li>
            <li *ngIf="ccucbmv1Selected checked " show> 
                <input class="wcs-checkbox" type="radio" name="checkbox-id" id="checkbox-id">
                <span class="wcs-checkmark">variablesDCUTerm.xml</span>
            </li>
            <li *ngIf="surferSelected checked " show> 
                <input class="wcs-checkbox" type="radio" name="checkbox-id" id="checkbox-id">
                <span class="wcs-checkmark">variablesDCUTerm.xml</span>
            </li>
            <li *ngIf="ccucbmv8Selected checked " show> 
                <input class="wcs-checkbox" type="radio" name="checkbox-id" id="checkbox-id">
                <span class="wcs-checkmark">variablesDCUTerm.xml</span>
            </li>
            <li *ngIf="ccucv3Selected checked " show>
                <input class="wcs-checkbox" type="radio" name="checkbox-id" id="checkbox-id">
                <span class="wcs-checkmark">variables config IP+MVB</span>
            </li>
            <li *ngIf="ccucv3Selected checked " show>
                <input class="wcs-checkbox" type="radio" name="checkbox-id" id="checkbox-id">
                <span class="wcs-checkmark">system config IP+MVB</span>
            </li>
            <li *ngIf="ccucv3Selected checked " show>
                <input class="wcs-checkbox" type="radio" name="checkbox-id" id="checkbox-id">
                <span class="wcs-checkmark">trigger engine config file</span>
            </li>
            <li *ngIf="ccucv3Selected checked " show> 
                <input class="wcs-checkbox" type="radio" name="checkbox-id" id="checkbox-id">
                <span class="wcs-checkmark">trigger engine rules</span>
            </li>
            <li *ngIf="ccucv3Selected checked " show>
                <input class="wcs-checkbox" type="radio" name="checkbox-id" id="checkbox-id">
                <span class="wcs-checkmark">CBM file transfer component config file</span>
            </li>
            <li *ngIf="surferSelected checked " show>
                <input class="wcs-checkbox" type="radio" name="checkbox-id" id="checkbox-id">
                <span class="wcs-checkmark">TE_rules.tar </span>
            </li>
            <li *ngIf="SboxV13Selected checked " show>
                <input class="wcs-checkbox" type="radio" name="checkbox-id" id="checkbox-id" >
                <span class="wcs-checkmark">sbox-x.x.xxx-Regio2N-xxxx-Linux.deb</span>
            </li>
            <li *ngIf="SboxV13Selected checked " show>
                <input class="wcs-checkbox" type="radio" name="checkbox-id" id="checkbox-id">
                <span class="wcs-checkmark">conf_group_ip.xml</span>
            </li > 
            <li *ngIf="SboxV13Selected checked " show>
                <input class="wcs-checkbox" type="radio" name="checkbox-id" id="checkbox-id">
                <span class="wcs-checkmark">config_dgf.json </span>
            </li>
            <li *ngIf="SboxV13Selected checked " show>
                <input class="wcs-checkbox" type="radio" name="checkbox-id" id="checkbox-id">
                <span class="wcs-checkmark">config_snapchot.json</span>
            </li>
            <li *ngIf="SboxV13Selected checked " show>
                <input class="wcs-checkbox" type="radio" name="checkbox-id" id="checkbox-id">
                <span class="wcs-checkmark">config_spybox.json</span>
            </li>
            <li *ngIf="SboxV13Selected checked " show>
                <input class="wcs-checkbox" type="radio" name="checkbox-id" id="checkbox-id">
                <span class="wcs-checkmark">ConfigurationOptions.txt</span>
            </li>
            <li *ngIf="SboxV13Selected checked " show>
                <input class="wcs-checkbox" type="radio" name="checkbox-id" id="checkbox-id">
                <span class="wcs-checkmark">ipt_config.xm</span>
            </li>
            <li *ngIf="SboxV13Selected checked " show>
                <input class="wcs-checkbox" type="radio" name="checkbox-id" id="checkbox-id">
                <span class="wcs-checkmark">tssp_config.xml</span>
            </li>
            <li *ngIf="NvrSelected checked " show>
                <input class="wcs-checkbox" type="radio" name="checkbox-id" id="checkbox-id">
                <span class="wcs-checkmark">xxxxxxxx_cpum_x.x.x.upd</span>
            </li>
            <li *ngIf="NvrSelected checked " show>
                <input class="wcs-checkbox" type="radio" name="checkbox-id" id="checkbox-id">
                <span class="wcs-checkmark">xxxxxxxx_cpue_x.x.x.upd</span>
            </li>
            <li *ngIf="NvrSelected checked " show>
                <input class="wcs-checkbox" type="radio" name="checkbox-id" id="checkbox-id">
                <span class="wcs-checkmark">s3131l_xxxxES.img</span>
            </li>
            <li *ngIf="NvrSelected checked " show>
                <input class="wcs-checkbox" type="radio" name="checkbox-id" id="checkbox-id">
                <span class="wcs-checkmark">X254049-1_20220413_193921_TRAIN_NVR_CONFIG-AGC-3C-OPTER_v3_22448708.cfg</span>
            </li>
            <li *ngIf="NvrSelected checked " show>
                <input class="wcs-checkbox" type="radio" name="checkbox-id" id="checkbox-id">
                <span class="wcs-checkmark">XNF-8010R_x.xx.xx_xxxxxxxx_R462.img</span>
            </li>
            <li *ngIf="NvrSelected checked " show>
                <input class="wcs-checkbox" type="radio" name="checkbox-id" id="checkbox-id">
                <span class="wcs-checkmark">ccu-os-sncf_521008v01.01.00.tar</span>
            </li>
            <li *ngIf="NvrSelected checked " show>
                <input class="wcs-checkbox" type="radio" name="checkbox-id" id="checkbox-id">
                <span class="wcs-checkmark">FullUpdate_APS-M_ACOREL_2.1.1.1.tar</span>
            </li>
            <li *ngIf="NvrSelected checked " show>
                <input class="wcs-checkbox" type="radio" name="checkbox-id" id="checkbox-id">
                <span class="wcs-checkmark">CCU_CAVE_S-DOT_AGC-3C_2.0.0.tar.gz</span>
            </li>
            <li *ngIf="NvrSelected checked " show> 
                <input class="wcs-checkbox" type="radio" name="checkbox-id" id="checkbox-id">
                <span class="wcs-checkmark">CCU_CAVE_S-DOT_AGC-4C_2.0.0.tar.gz</span>
            </li>
            <li *ngIf="NvrSelected checked " show>
                <input class="wcs-checkbox" type="radio" name="checkbox-id" id="checkbox-id">
                <span class="wcs-checkmark">CCU_CAVE_S-DOT_TER2NNG-3C_2.0.0.tar.gz</span>
            </li>
            <li *ngIf="NvrSelected checked " show>
                <input class="wcs-checkbox" type="radio" name="checkbox-id" id="checkbox-id">
                <span class="wcs-checkmark">CCU_CAVE_S-DOT_TER2NNG-3C-CFL_2.0.0.tar.gz</span>
            </li>
            <li *ngIf="NvrSelected checked " show>
                <input class="wcs-checkbox" type="radio" name="checkbox-id" id="checkbox-id">
                <span class="wcs-checkmark">CCU_CAVE_S-DOT_TER2NNG-4C_2.0.0.tar.gz </span>
            </li>
            <li *ngIf="NvrSelected checked " show>
                <input class="wcs-checkbox" type="radio" name="checkbox-id" id="checkbox-id">
                <span class="wcs-checkmark">CCU_CAVE_S-DOT_TER2NNG-5C_2.0.0.tar.gz</span>
            </li>
            <li *ngIf="NvrSelected checked " show>
                <input class="wcs-checkbox" type="radio" name="checkbox-id" id="checkbox-id">
                <span class="wcs-checkmark">APS-R_CAVE_S-Dot_AGC-3C_vv_pp</span>
            </li>
            <li *ngIf="NvrSelected checked " show>
                <input class="wcs-checkbox" type="radio" name="checkbox-id" id="checkbox-id">
                <span class="wcs-checkmark">APS-R_CAVE_S-Dot_AGC-4C_vv_pp</span>
            </li>
            <li *ngIf="NvrSelected checked " show>
                <input class="wcs-checkbox" type="radio" name="checkbox-id" id="checkbox-id">
                <span class="wcs-checkmark">APS-R_CAVE_S-Dot_TER2NNG-3C_vv_pp</span>
            </li>
            <li *ngIf="NvrSelected checked " show else hide>
                <input class="wcs-checkbox" type="radio" name="checkbox-id" id="checkbox-id">
                <span class="wcs-checkmark">APS-R_CAVE_S-Dot_TER2NNG-3C-CFL_vv_pp</span>
            </li>
            <li *ngIf="NvrSelected checked " show>
                <input class="wcs-checkbox" type="radio" name="checkbox-id" id="checkbox-id">
                <span class="wcs-checkmark">APS-R_CAVE_S-Dot_TER2NNG-4C_vv_pp</span>
            </li>
            <li *ngIf="NvrSelected checked " show>
                <input class="wcs-checkbox" type="radio" name="checkbox-id" id="checkbox-id">
                <span class="wcs-checkmark">APS-R_CAVE_S-Dot_TER2NNG-5C_vv_pp</span>
            </li>
            <li *ngIf="NvrSelected checked " show>
                <input class="wcs-checkbox" type="radio" name="checkbox-id" id="checkbox-id">
                <span class="wcs-checkmark">hmi_cfg_1.0.0.0.zip</span>
            </li>
            <li *ngIf="NvrSelected checked " show>
                <input class="wcs-checkbox" type="radio" name="checkbox-id" id="checkbox-id">
                <span class="wcs-checkmark">hmi_upd_1.0.0.0.zip</span>
            </li>
            <li *ngIf="NvrSelected checked " show>
                <input class="wcs-checkbox" type="radio" name="checkbox-id" id="checkbox-id">
                <span class="wcs-checkmark">cam_cfg_1.0.0.0.zip</span>
            </li>
            <li *ngIf="NvrSelected checked " show>
                <input class="wcs-checkbox" type="radio" name="checkbox-id" id="checkbox-id">
                <span class="wcs-checkmark">cam_upd_1.0.0.0.zip</span>
            </li>
            <li *ngIf="NvrSelected checked " show>
                <input class="wcs-checkbox" type="radio" name="checkbox-id" id="checkbox-id">
                <span class="wcs-checkmark">gateway_upd-xxx_1.0.0.0.zip</span>
            </li>
            <li *ngIf="ccucbmv1Selected selected " show>
                <input class="wcs-checkbox" type="radio" name="checkbox-id" id="checkbox-id">
                <span class="wcs-checkmark">hmi_cfg_1.0.0.0.zip</span>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>

</div>

<input #fcalc placeholder="Type fichier" >

<input #ftype placeholder="Type fichier" >

<wcs-button 
   class="wcs-success btn-pos" mode="clear" type="submit" value="Add flotte" 
   (click)="addflotte(
              flotteName.value,
              fEngins.valueAsNumber,
              fcalc.value,
              ftype.value
              
              );

            flotteName.value='';
            fEngins.values='';
            fcalc.value='';
            ftype.value=''                      
            ">
    <i class="material-icons">add</i>
    <span>Enregistrer une flotte</span>
</wcs-button>
```

**ts**

```
addflotte(name: string, fEngins: Array<Engins>, calculateur: string, type_fichier: string){
    name = name.trim();
    if (!name) { return; }

    fEngins = this.checkedList;
    if (!fEngins) { return;}

    calculateur = calculateur.trim();
    if (!calculateur) { return; }

    type_fichier = type_fichier.trim();
    if (!type_fichier) { return; }
    
  
    this.api.registerFlotte({ name, fEngins, calculateur, type_fichier } as unknown as Flotte)
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.flottes.push(data);
      });
  }
```

**service**

```
registerFlotte(flotte: Flotte): Observable<Flotte>
 {

   return this.http.post<Flotte>(this.base_url, flotte,  { headers: this.httpHeaders });
 }
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, you can only have `<tr>` as a child of `<tbody>`. And only `<td>` or `<th>` as child of `<tr>` Fix these mistakes first.

Comment: ok I didn't know, I don't have a problem on the board yet but thanks for that